# Why are Tucker and Malcolm not dead?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

I've been re-watching *Enterprise* and I have the same question I had the first time.

In episode 12 of season 4, **Babel One**, Tucker and Reed are running low on air while in environmental suits, and Tucker uses 100% pure oxygen to refill the suits. Is there something I've missed about the suits that makes this non lethal?

I'm not interested in the biology as that is certain death, but more about the suits from any series or movie, there must be something to prevent the oxygen being lethal - I'm looking for an explanation on that.

**Do they somehow manufacture nitrogen or another inert gas and if so why don't they just manufacture the oxygen, why didn't they die?**

All the questions are linked so answering any of them answers them all.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer, but even in the real world breathing 100% oxygen is not "certain death". It can be tolerated for a certain length of time under certain conditions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity

Comment: @MarkBeadles they were on that ship a lot longer than 96 minutes, even the low 6-10  min of that article suggests they shouldn't even be walking, so it doesn't change the question of what the suits do to protect people from that. They must do something or they would at least be on the floor

Comment: It's the partial pressure that is fatal, not the relative concentration.

Comment: @Matt - That "96 minutes" (if you are referring to the table in the wp article) is at a depth of 90' (27m) , which equals a pressure of 2.7 atmospheres.  100% oxygen at atmospheric pressure is not particularly dangerous (it's what fire-fighters breath).  If you look at the graph further down, you'll lose about 10% of your lung capacity if you breath pure oxygen for a *day*.

Comment: Matt, in short you can breathe pure O2 *if the pressure is low*.

Comment: @Fattie That has been mentioned and I have already admitted that my question may have been flawed in the comments because of that fact, I read all answers and comments, your comment on Peters post about 1 atmosphere is the reason for the question, its lethal, I didn't  consider lower pressures

Comment: See Apollo 1.  Pure Oxygen environment @5psi, the lethality was only because a fire started. A moon mission would have meant 3 days in that environment.

Comment: For what it's worth in anaesthesia we ventilate patients, depending on the anaesthetic method - volatile or intravenous - with up to 100% oxygen for several hours. If we use a volatile agent, then we use a percentage of the gas volume to carry the volatile anaesthetic, if it's an intravenous anaesthesia then the gas can be pure oxygen.

Comment: I can personally vouch for the fact that you can have 100% O2 at 2 atmospheres for a good 15 minutes without any negative effects if you're healthy - done it myself. It's also standard procedure for a much longer period of time in pressure chambers after dive accidents (although your chances to get something similar to a epileptic attack increase with pressure and time). At sea level, O2 poisoning from 100% O2 should only happen after a day or longer.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Current NASA spacesuits are filled with 100% oxygen at around 4psi so filling a spacesuit with pure oxygen is no issue assuming the pressure isn't too high. [reference](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/LM15_Portable_Life_Support_System_ppP1-5.pdf)

The actual percentage of gas doesn't matter when it comes to toxicity, what matters is the partial pressure of the gas which you get by multiplying the pressure by the percent. 20% atmospheric oxygen is equivalent to 100% oxygen at one fifth atmospheric pressure.

Spacesuits are not pressurised to full atmospheric pressure for this reason, so they only need to bring oxygen and it increases mobility to have less of a pressure difference between the inside and outside of the suit.

Comment: I'd like to see citations, but it seems like this answer is correct. Although at lower pressure, there are new concerns with decompression sickness.

Comment: The difference between full vacuum and full atmospheric pressure is only one atmosphere, divers are subjected to many times this (1atm every 30 feet) which is why decompression sickness is an issue. Being experienced spacers they would be well equipped to handle differences of one atmosphere, additionally, the treatment for decompression sickness is to be put in a 100% oxygen atmosphere so they already have a head start.

Comment: @Kai [This doc from Hamilton Standard](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/LM15_Portable_Life_Support_System_ppP1-5.pdf) describes the Apollo-era life support system and mentions using pure oxygen at 3.9 psi. Note also the Oxygen Purge System on pg. 4, which is designed to provide emergency life support by flushing the system with pure oxygen in an open loop.

Comment: @JohnMeacham I wasn't asking about biology but the suits instead, your answer is that nothing is needed other than to lower the pressure (which does render the  whole question mute), it seems my question was based on a faulty premise,, I was assuming full oxygen at normal pressure. I will accept this if no-one can give any better. I usually wait 24 hours before accepting. Thanks

Comment: IIRC, the reason a low pressure is used in space suits is that current space suits become quite hard to use with higher pressure. At higher pressure the person in the space suit has a difficult time moving around, due to the suit being basically a balloon that wants to maintain the largest volume and thus resists changes in arm and leg position. Given that a lower pressure is desired for that reason and that they still need to maintain a partial pressure of oxygen which will sustain the user, it results in choosing to use pure O2 at a low pressure. As usual, it's an engineering trade-off.

Comment: There's no need on this site for citations, for basic, everyday science.

Comment: Moot. Not mute.

Comment: @Makyen - not even really a tradeoff, is it? If low suit pressure both increases mobility and allows for use of 100% oxygen i.e. not having to lug around four times its weight in nitrogen, seems more like a convenient win-win.

Comment: @millimoose there are still tradeoffs, though the above comments didn't bring them up. For example, EVAs from the ISS require an oxygen pre-breathe to evacuate nitrogen from the astronauts' tissues.  (In an emergency situation this step could obvs be skipped)

Comment: @Fattie I'm sure it's deliberately ironic that references and citations are a fundamental cornerstone of basic, everyday science.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit , that's absolutely true on say the skeptics or math site.  But on, say, SO, one just *explains* the facts (how to solve the bug, make the boundary animate, or whatever), you don't "cite why you're right".  Similarly, here on the "tv discussion site" you need only state, explain, basic science when it happens to come up.  If some basic science fact came up, and, amazingly, someone wanted "proof", that would go to one of the science sites. That seems to be the way of it.  My take !

Comment: @Fattie I'm not necessarily disagreeing with you in this case. I just thought it was ironic, as I said.

Comment: true, that's a good point @LightnessRacesinOrbit  :)  and funny :)

Answer (score 5):

There are two main things to consider here.

1. Oxygen toxicity depends on the partial pressure of oxygen. In a low pressure environment you need 100% oxygen to achive a breathable suit atmosphere without making the suit unusablly stiff. As I understand it at 1 earth atmosphere you can breathe pure oxygen for many hours, at higher pressures the safe exposure time drops dramatically.
2. The human body consumes a lot of oxygen. Nitrogen (or other dilutent gas) on the other hand is not directly consumed by the body.

Given the relatively low bulk of the suits we can assume they use a rebreather system rather than an open-cycle system.

If the suits are intended for short duration use at pressures of 1 earth atmosphere or less then it is likely a pure oxygen system would suffice and would be the simplest and most reliable system. This is how real world spacesuits work.

On other other hand if the suits are designed to work at pressures significantly above 1 earth atmosphere or to work at 1 atmosphere for long durations they would need to have a mixing system. Sensors would be needed to keep track of the gas mixture inside the suit and adjust accordingly. This is done today in diving rebreathers, so it's not something that needs magical future technology. The oxygen and the dilutent gas would presumablly be stored seperately by the suit.

Comment: "As I understand it at 1 earth atmosphere you can breathe pure oxygen for many hours, at higher pressures the safe exposure time drops dramatically."  This is wrong.  O2 at 1 atmosphere == instant death.  O2 at 1/5th atmosphere == all good.

Comment: All the sources that my searches are turning up say at 1 ATM you have hours (though they disagree on exactly how many hours). Your "instant death" claim doesn't pass the sniff test given the use of pure oxygen in some types of diving and the use of pure oxygen throughout the apollo missions (in space it was low pressure pure O2, but in the runup to launch it was at atmospheric pressure).

Comment: @Fattie As a scuba diver who's breathed pure O2 for a time at 2 ATM to decompress, I can guarantee O2 at 1 ATM is not instant death. Pure O2 is used in tons of breathing applications at 1 ATM for short durations without adverse effects.

Comment: @Fattie ["100% oxygen can be tolerated at sea level for about 24-48 hours without any severe tissue damage."](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK430743/#_article-26493_s6_)

Comment: You can go to oxygen bars at trendy clubs and breath pure oxygen for ten bucks without any issues. Even at high pressure it isn't "instant death".

Comment: Peter, you're right, "instant" was a poor choice of hyperbole.  I meant "instant" in the sense of "the plague - instant death!"  :)